# Azure Functions Runtime Install "Sequence contains more than one matching element"

Tags: azure-functions-runtime

I am getting the following error while trying to configure IIS. It is a brand new install

[image]

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. It happened that I had another website in my local IIS, which is configured to use SSL on port 443. Deleting the website solved the problem.